# System.Xml.Linq.XElement does not have Load method when building UWP

Tags: c#, .net, xml, uwp

I created a new UWP app and wanted to load an XML file using the xelement class.
While looking on mdsn, I see I can do this using the load(string) method
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx

In my UWP project the xelement is missing the Load method.

Why is this happening ? 
Is it because I am not actually using the .NET while building UWP apps ? Or I am using a subset of .NET while building UWP apps ?

While looking on msdn how can I verify if a method from a .NET class is also available while developing a UWP app ?

Comment: That does sound odd - I've just tried creating a UWP app, and `XElement.Load(string)` is definitely available. Could you give details of your project... and include the exact compiler error you're getting when you try to use it?

Comment: Documentation says this method is [available in UWP since version 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298435%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can verify this information in _Version Information_ section on each page

Comment: I have Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015, version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3. Microsoft .Net Framework Version 4.6.01586. I created a new project from the templates Blank App (universal windows) in Visual C# with .Net Framework 4.6.1 with windows Target version Build 14393 and minimum version 14393. After that I declared an Xelement and tried in the constructor of the class to use the Load method and it does not appear

Comment: What do you mean by _it does not appear_? IntelliSense is not displaying it as one of possible options? You are saying something about constructor - do you mean constructor of some of your classes or `XElement`'s constructor? Do you realize `Load(string)` is a static method, so you should invoke it like `var doc = XElement.Load(path)`?

Comment: I am using the constructor in a class I built. Indeed, I had missed the fact that it is static... my fault. Still for other classes I am not able to access their methods, like for example System.Xml.XmlElement var1 and trying to do var1.SelectSingleNode(String), it does not appear in IntelliSense (SelectSingleNode)

Comment: Yes, it has solved the problem. Do not have enough reputation to up-vote the answer. Thank you for the help !

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). There is no reputation limit for accepting answers and you can also gain +2 reputation after accepting someone's answer. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it because I am not actually using the .NET while building UWP apps ? Or I am using a subset of .NET while building UWP apps ?

The .Net APIs that can be used in UWP apps is called [.NET for UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185501.aspx). .NET for UWP apps provides a set of managed types that you can use to create Universal Windows Platform apps for Windows 10 using C# or Visual Basic. Note that .NET for UWP apps includes a subset of the types provided in the full .NET Framework for each namespace.

> While looking on msdn how can I verify if a method from a .NET class is also available while developing a UWP app ?

As @Paweł Hemperek said, usually, we can find if a .NET Framework class is available in UWP apps by checking the **Version Information** in the bottom of the document. If we can find **Universal Windows Platform** under **Version Information** then we should be able to use this class in UWP apps.

But please note that one class can be used in UWP not means that all of its properties and methods are available in UWP. For example, [XmlElement Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement(v=vs.110).aspx) is available in UWP, but [XmlNode.SelectSingleNode Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw(v=vs.110).aspx) can't be used in UWP apps.